# Does CodeName One support MYSQL BLOBs using RESTful Database Interface?

Tags: mysql, netbeans, glassfish, codenameone

Using CodenameOne web database extension, I can get basic SQL fields to work for strings and numbers, but not for large binary objects BLOBs. I'm following the instructions here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-part-2.html
Are BLOBs supported by CodenameOne?  If so how do you do it?  I can't find any examples that use BLOB types.

I've tried using long strings, and with the MarianaDB, can get up to 512K string size, but I need to store images which can be larger.

MariaDB [(none)]> use tsg; desc photos;
Database changed
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| player_id  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tree_id    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| photo_type | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image      | blob             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

When I add the record without the blob it works:

```
    m.put("playerId", "1");
    m.put("treeId", "2");
    m.put("photoType", "front");
    m.put("image", null);

    client.create(m, res -> {
        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println("create result = " + res);
    });
```

outputs:
{treeId=2, image=null, photoType=front, playerId=1}
create result = true

But when I try to add the blob, it does not:

```
    m.put("playerId", "1");
    m.put("treeId", "2");
    m.put("photoType", "front");
    byte bytes[] = new byte[100];
    m.put("image", bytes);

    client.create(m, res -> {
        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println("create result = " + res);
    });
```

outputs:

{treeId=2, image=[B@5968c8cb, photoType=front, playerId=1}
create result = false

Help!  I'm using BLOBs in the wrong way, or does CN1 not support BLOBs?

The only error message is from the result of create being false.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have builtin support for that at this time. You can use [MultipartRequest](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html) to submit binary data to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the info Shai!  Since my last post, I was able to use the MutlipartRequest to upload large jpgs and mp4s.  Probably more efficient than uploading as a BLOB.  I'm testing on max size now, but I was able to move a 65MB video file easily and efficiently from my Android phone to the server.